# Rails, select helper, adding style

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
 select :model, :attribute, :style => "some:style;"
```

Add `style` to the `select helper` in rails, but it is not working.

Comment: This is a very serious question I've tried to find answer to and deserves many up votes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [documenation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001624):

`select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})`

So your `:style` hash needs to be the 5th parameter. For example:

```
select(:model, :attribute, @options_for_select, { }, { :style => 'some: style' }
```

Comment: Anything you want. That last parameter just creates HTML attributes on the select element, so a hash like this:

`{ :class => 'myclass', :style => 'display: inline;' }`

would create:

`<select class="myclass" style="display: inline;">...</select>`

Comment: how to make it responsive i mean.. i want my select tag to get width of selected values length.. can anybody suggest something