# How to change html of the select form helper in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

When I used the select_tag helper, everything was working perfect with:

```
<%= select_tag :district_id, options_from_collection_for_select(districts, "id", "title", prompt: "All"), { class: "select", id: "district" } %>
```

But I can't handle the select helper. Tried changing these ways:

1) `<%= form.select :district_id, options_from_collection_for_select(districts, "id", "title", prompt: "All"), html_options: { class: "select_inside_col", id: "locality" } %>`

2) `<%= form.select :district_id, options_from_collection_for_select(districts, "id", "title", prompt: "All"), html: { class: "select_inside_col", id: "locality" } %>`

3) `<%= form.select :district_id, options_from_collection_for_select(districts, "id", "title", prompt: "All"), class: "select_inside_col", id: "locality" %>`

The result is always the same - it ignores html options(`<select name="district_id" id="district_id">`), however, options_from_collection_for_select work fine.
What's the trick?

Comment: Found the best answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301910/rails-select-helper-adding-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as per the documentation [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select):

```
<%= form.select :district_id, districts.map { |d| [d.title, d.id] }, { include_blank: "All" }, { class: "select_inside_col", id: "locality" } %>
```

Note, it takes the collection of districts as 2nd argument directly (not wrapped in `options_from_collection_for_select`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, it works partly (for example, the element applies  'selected'), because still I can't override the id of the select element and apply class :(